# Use phantom js with node modules installed globally in system

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, phantomjs

I installed phantom js version 2.1.1 by downloading it from the [official site](http://phantomjs.org/download.html). Then I extracted the tar.bz2 file and installed it in python way. So phantom Js is working well but I want to use some node modules installed globally inside my script for phantom js. Its not happening with simple require 'node_module'. What should I do?

My OS - Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: PhantomJS doesn't know about the global npm package repository. You will need to use an explicit path to the global module.

Comment: Can you please show any example code?

Comment: And what if I install some npm module locally?

Comment: If you'll use a local npm module, then PhantomJS will find it, but don't forget that PhantomJS has nothing to do with node.js. You generally can't use node.js modules with PhantomJS. Some modules can be used in both, though.